# Communication between wcf and windows service?

Tags: windows, wcf, makefile

I have a situation where I want to establish communication between WCF service and Windows service.

1. I want to pass messages from the Windows service to the WCF service
2. I want to send array list from the Windows service to the WCF service

How can I achieve this?

Edit:WCF is hosted on IIS.
if any code snippets it would very helpfull.
Thanks in advance
loke

Comment: Is your Windows service *hosting* the WCF service? (via a `ServiceHost` class?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, just add a reference to your wcf service in your windows service.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio right-click your project and choose Add Service Reference. Enter your WCF service address and choose namespace name. Visual Studio will download WSDL from you web service and create proxy for you.

Then just create proxy object and call web service methods:

```
YourNamespace.YourServiceClient client = new YourNamespace.YourServiceClient();
client.Open();
client.YourOperation();
client.Close();
```